# I planted raw almonds and they got very moldy. What to do?

Tags: mold

Before planting 20-something almonds I've read on various forums that people have encountered mold growing over theirs and destroying the seeds. After about a week from planting, I'm seeing a very thin white layer of mold on the surface of the soil and all around the almonds especially. Various sources recommend to sprinkle baking soda, apple cider vinegar or cinnamon on the mold, and claim it wouldn't harm the plants (nuts still in my case). But the mold seems too intense at this point. Maybe I should do something else?

I don't think the problem is in the soil, because other seeds and plants have been growing in the same soil just fine. The raw almonds probably already came infested with mold.

Comment: sounds like damping off - cinnamon is said to work, but I don't know if it does, never tried it. Its probably worth a try... I think you're supposed to use it as a preventative rather than a treatment, but I'd still try it.

Answer (score 3):

Do not worry about mycelium on and in the soil.  If your almond seed was moldy then they just won't germinate.  Soil is always full of fungal spores.  When the soil gets disturbed, water added, some of those spores will grow.  No big deal.  If your seeds were moldy they just won't germinate.  Nothing more insidious. [Germination of almond seeds](http://homeguides.sfgate.com/germination-period-almonds-51375.html)

DO NOT add anything right now!  No vinegar, baking soda, my goodness.  One actually lowers pH possibly making your soil uninhabitable by any plant and the latter raises the pH.  pH is a big deal.  One never adds anything to the soil unless they have a soil test and knows soils, chemistry and plants!

More than likely the mold, if any on the almonds, is NOT the fungus/mycelium you are seeing in the soil.  You can't believe the amount and diversity of fungal spores in garden soil!